# ¿Cómo hacer un Login seguro con Base de datos Local?

Tags: python

Tengo un programa que al inicio, pide :

- nombre de usuario
- contraseña.

Estos son almacenados dentro de la computadora.

**¿Hay alguna manera segura de encriptarlos?**

Esto para lograr más seguridad que tenerlos dentro del código o de un 'txt'

Entonces, el programa pide el usuario y su respectiva contraseña dando 3 intentos. Si los falla, el programa cierra.

Comment: Mathias, las contraseñas no se encriptan, no hagas eso por que es absolutamente inseguro. Lo que se hace es generar un HASH mediante algún algoritmo y se guarda, este dato no es más que es una representación numérica de la contraseña, luego cuando el usuario vuelve a  "logearse" se compara el HASH de la contraseña con el guardado si coinciden, adentro. Investiga por ese lado, MD5 y SHA1 hoy por hoy se los considera inseguros, apunta para el lado de SHA2/3. Trata de ser más concreto en tu pregunta,como está planteada es demasiado amplia. Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mathias, en primer lugar, la encriptación o más correctamente el cifrado, es un tipo de algoritmo que se encarga de alterar un mensaje para hacerlo inteligible a terceros que no conocen dicho algoritmo. Un mensaje o contraseña cifrada sigue existiendo, dentro del cifrado, esto es muy importante de entender, ya que aquí radica el principal problema de guardar una contraseña cifrada, cualquier que "robe" una contraseña cifrada se "roba" la contraseña, los algoritmos de cifrados eventualmente se pueden "romper", es cuestión de tiempo y recursos. Si tu necesidad apunta a algo pequeño con pocos usuarios dentro de una LAN y tan solo necesitas ocultar las contraseñas, tal vez no importe mucho esto, pero es bueno que quede claro: **No deberíamos guardar contraseñas cifradas, hacerlo crea una vulnerabilidad muy crítica en cualquier sistema**.

Ejemplos de algoritmos de cifrado: [DES](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Encryption_Standard), [RSA](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA), [Blowfish](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blowfish), [AES](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard)

#### ¿Que hacer entonces con las contraseñas?

Originalmente pensábamos en guardar la contraseña simplemente para validar el proceso de "login", es decir para comparar la contraseña ingresada por el usuario con la contraseña guardada, si son la misma entonces permitimos el ingreso. Acá entra a jugar otro tipo de algoritmo totalmente distinto que generalmente los conocemos como algoritmos de [HASH o funciones resumen](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Funci%C3%B3n_hash), estos algoritmos generan a partir de una determinada entrada, una cadena "resumen" de un tamaño determinado independientemente del tamaño del mensaje de entrada. El HASH generado es determinista, siempre que lo apliquemos a la misma cadena obtendremos el mismo HASH, pero lo más importante, no guardan de ninguna manera el mensaje de entrada, por eso se las conoce como funciones resumen. Esto hace que en un escenario de un "robo" de cadenas HASH, el proceso de encontrar las contraseñas sea algo más complicado, en teoría bastante más. El principal problema de cualquier HASH son las colisiones, es decir, la posibilidad de encontrar una cadena cualquiera que tenga el mismo HASH que por ejemplo una contraseña válida. Por esto, algoritmos que eran estándar como MD5 o SHA1 hasta hace algunos años, dejen de ser recomendados por que se ha logrado generar colisiones en tiempos razonables, esto no quiere decir que dejen de usarse, simplemente que se los deja de usar en aplicaciones criptográficas.

En Python tenemos el módulo [hashlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html) que nos ofrece una amplia serie de algoritmos de hash. Podemos usar alguna de las variantes de [SHA-2](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2), de la siguiente forma:

```
import hashlib
m = hashlib.sha256()
m.update(b"Esta es una password")

# En formato binario
print(m.digest())
b'\x12\x94E\x02\x18\xca*\x16Y~;\x0by\xfe\xc8\xd7E\x8eq9\xe4\x04\x9c\x83\xefZIa\xc0K\xb6\t'

# En formato hexadecimal
print(m.hexdigest())
1294450218ca2a16597e3b0b79fec8d7458e7139e4049c83ef5a4961c04bb609
```

Para validar una contraseña, simplemente tendríamos que grabar la salida de `digest()` o de `hexdigest()`, Por ejemplo:

```
hash_password = m.hexdigest()
```

y luego en el siguiente login repetir la rutina de HASH y comparar así:

```
m = hashlib.sha256()
m.update(b"Esta es otra password")
if m.hexdigest() == hash_password:
  print("Contraseña correcta")
else:
  print("Contraseña incorrecta!!")
```

Comment: Aclaraste mis dudas :D !
Muchas Gracias y perdón por mi ignorancia en estos temas.

Comment: @MathiasHilgert, no hay nada que perdonar, todos venimos acá a aprender. Saludos.